# Is there singular/plural list on the web?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, dictionaries

Sometime it's necessary to determine if a word is singular or plural (to know which article to use or not to use).
Is there some kind of dictionary that tells whether a word is singular or plural?

Answer (score 1):

Any dictionary can be used for this.

For example, here's the entry for *gravy* on dictionary.com:

[image]

If you look up *gravy* it will lead you to this entry, telling you that *gravy* is a singular (or mass) noun.

If you look up *gravies* it will also lead you to this entry, telling you that *gravies* is the plural of *gravy*.

Essentially any dictionary or dictionary website will provide similar information.

In comments you added,

> it's not always clear. If I type dog, water, system it shows nothing about plural/singular.

First, the dictionary entry will always be for the singular form, unless it's one of the rare words that only exists as a plural. So the fact you found entries for *dog*, *system* and *water* indicates these are singular nouns.

The form of the plural isn't shown because those nouns form the plural simply by adding 's' (i.e. *dogs*, *systems*, *waters*), which is the most common way of forming a plural in English.

In the case of a noun that are only seen in the plural without a corresponding singular form, like [*arrears*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/arrears?s=t), the part of speech will be given as "plural noun" rather than just "noun".

Comment: However, it's not always clear. If I type `dog`, `water`, `system` it shows nothing about plural/singular. So I can't tell if I have to use any articles with `system` or `water`.